# optimization of if statement having always the same value after the first evaluation

Tags: c, compilation

Is there some macro or optimization tricks in C that could tell the program : this if statement will be either true or false, but it will have always the same value after the first evaluation, example :
let's say you want to make program, which will in first parse some argument, and then go in a big while, each iteration you have to display some information in a certain way (chosen by args given), so each time you will ask if (some args have been given -> print info this way), else (print info another way), but this condition will always be true or false since the parsing part is in first and can't be changed when you enter in the while.

Comment: This sort of thing isn't managed by changing how the compiler optimises code.   It is better to use standard C code - for example, variables to control how often the test is done, and hold previous results if needed.   That is independent of compiler optimisation, and guaranteed to work with all compilers and optimisation settings (assuming a compiler that correctly complies with the applicable C standard).

Answer (score 0):

If the checking condition is expensive and you know how many times you have to loop you can do this.

```
if(Time_expensive_condition_check){
    while(number_of_iterations){
        //your code here
        number_of_iterations = number_of_iterations - 1
    }
}
```

But if your condition check is not time expensive and only O(1) then there is no more optimisation since in each iteration you have to check wether to stop or continue the loop.